# php function not adding column to database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having trouble with a very general php function.

The idea behind it is to add a (TEXT type) column to a table if it does not exist.  My php is as follows:

```
function add_column($conn, $table, $colname){

    // Prepare and execute statment 1
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '$colname'");
    if (!$sql->execute()){

        // Prepare and execute statment 2
        $sql1 = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE `ExamServer`.$table ADD `$colname` TEXT");
        $sql1->execute();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated huys thank you!!

Comment: Notice that you query is open to SQL Injections, if you dont check `$table` and `$colname`. You already use prepared statements, so you should bind both variables as parameters to the prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can check if column exists using following query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM  `$table` WHERE field = '$colname'
```

You will get one row if column is there. If not you can perform `ALTER` query.

```
if($sql->num_rows == 0) {
    // Perform your alter query here
}
```

Comment: brilliant thank you very much!! this worked, sorry its my misunderstanding of the connection between php and sql, pretty new to it!

Answer (score 2):

First issue: The first prepared statement.

Instead of checking whether the first statement yielded true or false, since you're checking if this row exists, just use `->num_rows` instead.

Second issue: The second prepared statement. You query is missing `COLUMN` from your `ADD`, so this should be:

```
ALTER TABLE $table ADD COLUMN $colname TEXT
```

Final code:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '%$colname%'"); // add wildcard
$sql->execute();
if($sql->num_rows <= 0) { // if this column does not exist, do the if block
    $sql->store_result(); // this line is important for the second prepared statement to work
     // Prepare and execute statment 2
    $sql1 = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE $table ADD COLUMN $colname TEXT");
    $sql1->execute();
}
```

Final note: If this is a user input and want to bind those, you cannot bind identifiers, you could whitelist them though.

Comment: This is a wild card. you cant use `%`. You have to be precise.

Comment: @Shreejibawa the OP just need to remove that if he/she needs precision, there's not enough context on how this search is used so i just added just in case, very easy to remove anyway

Comment: Great explanation thank you! this certainly cleared things up for me!! Kudos to the "Dead Space" profile picture btw